# Setting up python in sourceforge

Tags: python, cgi, sourceforge

I am trying to host a sample program test.py in my sourceforge repository. I uploaded my file from the directory `/home/project-web/motiur/cgi-bin/` and then went to `motiur.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/test.py`. Unfortunately I got an error that suggests premature end of headers .

The source code of test.py :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import cgi, cgitb
print "Content-type:text/html\n"
print "<html><body>This is another test</body></html>"
```

The exact error is:

```
An error has been encountered in accessing this page. 
  1. Server: motiur.sourceforge.net 
  2. URL path: /cgi-bin/test.py 
  3. Error notes: Premature end of script headers: test.py 
  4. Error type: 500 
  5. Request method: GET 
  6. Request query string: 
  7. Time: 2013-01-12 14:49:39 UTC (1358002179)
```

BTW, I am using filezilla in windows and had set the file permission to 755, that is everybody can execute the file. This a noob question, a little help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @YannisRizos: The error is ;                                       An error has been encountered in accessing this page.

1. Server: motiur.sourceforge.net 
2. URL path: /cgi-bin/test.py 
3. Error notes: Premature end of script headers: test.py 
4. Error type: 500 
5. Request method: GET 
6. Request query string: 
7. Time: 2013-01-12 14:49:39 UTC (1358002179)

Comment: Take a look at the article [Premature end of script headers](http://htmlfixit.com/cgi-tutes/tutorial_Common_Web_dev_error_messages_and_what_they_mean.php#premature). One thing I noticed that's different is they have an extra newline at the end of the `print "Content-type:text/html\n\n"`.

Comment: @martineau: Sorry , the problem still persists , even after your change .

Comment: See [Installing your CGI script on a Unix system](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#installing-your-cgi-script-on-a-unix-system) in the docs.

Comment: How about `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print 'Content-type: text/html'
print ''
print '<html><body>This is another test</body></html>'
```

You might need two '\n\n' before the body of the response.

**Edit**

Then try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

At the top instead of

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

Comment: Sorry the error persists . Is there any problem with the line of code:    `#!/usr/local/bin/python
import cgi, cgitb`. By the way my code runs just fine in my localhost . I am suspecting the linking of the python interpreter and my access link of my test.py file .

Comment: Sorry , I am still getting `premature end of script headers` error . You can visit the site at http://motiur.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/test.py to see the error .

Comment: Is sourceforge using python 3? If so, you'll need parentheses around the strings.

Comment: Nope , its using python 2.4.3 ; strangely enough !

Comment: Then I would try deploying elsewhere. 2.4.3 is so ancient no one can reasonably support it. Someone should yell at SourceForge for this.

Comment: Any suggestions ; how about heroku , yes .. no ?

Comment: With your script as it is, I think you'll have an easier time at PythonAnywhere. I'm not sure how well Heroku works with a plain CGI script honestly.